# How is "information relating to the safety of flight" defined by the FAA?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules

[14 CFR 91.183](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=dfacf918de4cdc45d4428fe477a12ab4&mc=true&node=se14.2.91_1183&rgn=div8) states:

> Unless otherwise authorized by ATC, the pilot in command of each aircraft operated under IFR must report the following as soon as possible: Any unforecast weather conditions encountered; and any other **information relating to the safety of flight**.

This language is very vague and probably causes a lot of confusion for pilots who are studying it. Does the FAA elaborate on this concept or provide an examples or a more specific definition somewhere else? If not, what are some examples of reports ATC would expect based on this reg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The language is ***intentionally*** vague.
Much like Justice Stewart said about pornography, when it comes to "information relating to the safety of flight" [you'll know it when you see it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)

- Birds flying around in the approach path? Yup.
- Wind shear on short final? Yup.
  (Even if it's forecast/reported telling them how much airspeed you gained or lost helps.)
- "Drone" buzzing around in the traffic pattern? Yup.
- Deer grazing in the middle of a grass runway? Yup.
- Bird strike? Absolutely.
  (There are regs/procedures specifically for this.)
- The guy in row 3J is threatening the flight attendants? Yup.
- The guy in row 3J spilled his soda on his lap? …Not so much.

Comment: Ha I love this answer! Thank you! Also it helped me realize that it's not vague because of lawyer bullcrap (well maybe a little), but it's vague because reporting information that affect the safety of flight can make things safer for everyone. Also what's the reg that specifically requires reporting of a bird strike?

Comment: @RyanBurnette From a regulatory perspective I don't think there's a specific rule for wildlife strikes (though they can be swept up in things that cause "substantial damage" depending on where and how the bird hits the aircraft, and I think there may be something in Part 139 for airport operators). The FAA's [Wildlife Strike Database](http://wildlife.faa.gov) is mostly bird-related incidents though, and theres a tidy little mini-bureaucracy for dealing with that stuff.

Comment: `tidy little mini-bureaucracy` There is nothing `tidy`, `little` or `mini` about bureaucracy. That was, however, a nice turn of phrase. ;)

Comment: @RyanBurnette, it's vague most of all because real life is complicated and there is simply no chance to create an even remotely complete list off the table.